# How come when I return a variable in a function and print it in another function it isn't printing

Tags: python

I am writing a discord bot that when I write `?start` it constantly checks for if a text file changes and if it does, it gets the last line of the text file and saves it to the variable `avatarid`. When I print `avatarid` in the function `look` if I write `print(avatarid)` it will print the avatar id but, if I `return` `avatarid` and print it in the async function called start (a bot command) it doesnt print anything.

My Code:

```
class Watcher(object):
    running = True
    refresh_delay_secs = 1

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, watch_file, call_func_on_change=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self._cached_stamp = 0
        self.filename = watch_file
        self.call_func_on_change = call_func_on_change
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    # Look for changes
    def look(self):
        stamp = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
        if stamp != self._cached_stamp:
            self._cached_stamp = stamp
            # File has changed, so do something...
            with open("\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\VRChat\\PythonLogger.txt", "r") as file:
                for last_line in file:
                    pass
            avatarid_old = last_line
            avatarid = avatarid_old.replace("\n", "")
            #avatar_id = self.look()
            #print(avatarid)
            if self.call_func_on_change is not None:
                self.call_func_on_change(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            return avatarid

    # Keep watching in a loop        
    def watch(self):
        while self.running: 
            try: 
                # Look for changes
                time.sleep(self.refresh_delay_secs) 
                avatarid = self.look() 
                #avatarid = self.look()
            except KeyboardInterrupt: 
                print('\nDone') 
                break 
            except FileNotFoundError:
                # Action on file not 
                pass
           # except: 
                #print('Unhandled error: %s' % sys.exc_info()[0])


def custom_action(text):
    print(text)
watch_file = '\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\VRChat\\PythonLogger.txt'



#start command
@bot.command(name='start')
async def start(ctx):
    """starts the bot"""
    await ctx.message.delete()
    watcher = Watcher(watch_file, custom_action, text='File Changed!')  # also call custom action function
    watcher.watch()  # start the watch going
    #avatarid = self.look()

    print(avatarid)
    av_id = avatarid.strip()
    response = requests.post("https://vrcpanel.com/test/vrcadownload", data={"avatarid":av_id, "login":"Download+VRCA"}, allow_redirects=False)

    url = f'https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/avatars/{avatarid}?apiKey=JlE5Jldo5Jibnk5O5hTx6XVqsJu4WJ26'
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req)
    data = json.load(webpage)
    #await ctx.send(data['name'])
    check_description = ''
    if data['description'] == data['name']:
        check_description = "Avatar has no description."
    else:
        check_description = data['description']

    embed = discord.Embed(title=data['name'], description=check_description, color=0x0000FF)
    embed.set_image(url=data['thumbnailImageUrl'])
    embed.add_field(name="Download:", value=(response.headers["Location"]))
    embed.add_field(name='Uploaded:', value=data['created_at'])
    embed.add_field(name='Status:', value=data['releaseStatus'])
    embed.add_field(name='Author:', value=data['authorName'])
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or does the print command return nothing?

Comment: it just prints nothing

Comment: There is no way all this code is needed to reproduce your problem. Please take the time to reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to make it as short as I can now.

Answer (score 0):

The `avatarid` variable is internal to the Watcher class, so it can't be accessed outside of it. Also, the `self` variable generally used to identify a class's own functions. That means you'll have to direct the function to the object, rather than "self". Try correcting `#avatarid = self.look()` to `avatarid = watcher.look()`

Another way to approach this is to add an avatarid attribute in the class by using the `self` variable e.g:

```
self.avatarid = avatarid_old.replace("\n", "")
```

You can then call this, again using your watcher object:

```
print(watcher.avatarid)
```

Comment: In the function `look` I changed 
`avatarid = avatarid_old.replace("\n", "")`
 to
 `self.avatarid = avatarid_old.replace("\n", "")`
and in the async function `start` I changed `print(avatarid)` to `print(watcher.avatarid)`
but it is still not printing.